# How to link 'Sign Up' page to 'Log In' with html/javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, authentication

I am having some trouble linking the "Sign Up" form to make it save to my database so it can then be logged into by the user who created the sign up login.

I have both a Sign Up page and a Login page made (obviously) and I have the scripts to validate the e-mail and all of that already. All I need to know is some advice or perhaps a code.

This is the "Sign Up" page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<style>
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 }
body{
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 }
#container{
 width:550px;
 background-color:rgba(250,250,252,.9);
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 box-shadow:0 0 3px #999;
 }
#container_body{
 padding:20px;
 }
.form_title{
 font-size:35px;
 color:#141823;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
 font-weight:normal;
 }
.head_para{
 font-size:19px;
 color:#99a2a7;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:normal;
 }
#form_name{
 padding:25px 0 0 15px;
 }
.firstnameorlastname{
  margin-right:20px;
 }
.input_name{
 width:207px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#email_form{
 clear:both;
 padding:15px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_email{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#Re_email_form{
 padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_Re_email{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
#password_form{
 padding:10px 0 10px 0px;
 }
.input_password{
 width:434px;
 padding:5px;
 font-size:18px;
 }
.birthday_title{
 font-size:16px; 
 color:#8b919d; 
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:0 0 10px 0;
 }
select{
 padding:5px;
 }
#birthday{
 font-size:12px;
 color:#8b919d;
 padding-top:10px;
 }
#radio_button{
 padding:10px 0 0 0;
 }
#sign_user{
 font-size:14px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#3B5998;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
#errorBox{
 color:#F00;
 }
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="emptyDiv"></div>
<div id="description"></div>
<!--container start-->
<div id="container">
  <div id="container_body">
    <div>
      <h2 class="form_title">User Registration Form</h2>
      <p class="head_para">Form Validated Using Javascript</p>
    </div>
    <!--Form  start-->
    <div id="form_name">
      <div class="firstnameorlastname">
       <form name="form" >
       <div id="errorBox"></div>
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  class="input_name" >
        <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_name" >

      </div>
      <div id="email_form">
        <input type="text" name="Email" value=""  placeholder="Your Email" class="input_email">
      </div>
      <div id="Re_email_form">
        <input type="text" name="enterEmail" value=""  placeholder="Re-enter Email" class="input_Re_email">
      </div>
      <div id="password_form">
        <input type="password" name="Password" value=""  placeholder="New Password" class="input_password">
      </div>
      <!--birthday details start-->
      <div>
        <h3 class="birthday_title">Birthday</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="birthday_month" >
          <option value="" selected >Month</option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option>
          <option value="2">Feb</option>
          <option value="3">Mar</option>
          <option value="4">Apr</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="birthday_day" >
          <option value="" selected>Day</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="birthday_year">
          <option value="" selected>Year</option>
          <option value="2013">2013</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
          <option value="2011">2011</option>
          <option value="2010">2010</option>
          <option value="2009">2009</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!--birthday details ends-->
      <div id="radio_button">
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
        <label >Female</label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
        <label >Male</label>
      </div>
       <div>
        <p id="sign_user" onClick="Submit()">Sign Up </p>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    <!--form ends-->
  </div>
</div>
<script type= "text/javascript">

function Submit(){
 var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
 var fname = document.form.Name.value,
  lname = document.form.LastName.value,
  femail = document.form.Email.value,
  freemail = document.form.enterEmail.value,
  fpassword = document.form.Password.value,
  fmonth = document.form.birthday_month.value,
  fday = document.form.birthday_day.value,
  fyear = document.form.birthday_year.value;

 if( fname == "" )
   {
     document.form.Name.focus() ;
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
     return false;
   }
 if( lname == "" )
   {
     document.form.LastName.focus() ;
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
     return false;
   }

   if (femail == "" )
 {
  document.form.Email.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the email";
  return false;
  }else if(!emailRegex.test(femail)){
  document.form.Email.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
  return false;
  }

   if (freemail == "" )
 {
  document.form.enterEmail.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the email";
  return false;
  }else if(!emailRegex.test(freemail)){
  document.form.enterEmail.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the valid email";
  return false;
  }

  if(freemail !=  femail){
   document.form.enterEmail.focus();
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "emails are not matching, re-enter again";
   return false;
   }


 if(fpassword == "")
  {
   document.form.Password.focus();
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the password";
   return false;
  }

   if (fmonth == "") {
        document.form.birthday_month.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday month";
        return false;
     }
  if (fday == "") {
        document.form.birthday_day.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday day";
        return false;
     }
  if (fyear == "") {
        document.form.birthday_year.focus();
  document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select the birthday year";
        return false;
     }
  if(document.form.radiobutton[0].checked == false && document.form.radiobutton[1].checked == false){
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "select your gender";
    return false;
   }
  if(fname != '' && lname != '' && femail != '' && freemail != '' && fpassword != '' && fmonth != '' && fday != '' && fyear != ''){
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
   alert("Form Submitted Successfully");
   window.location = "Books.html";
   }

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Login page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #submit{
    position: relative;
     font-size:14px;
     color:#FFF;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#3B5998;
     padding:10px;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
    p {
    color: blue;


    }


    </style>





        </head>
        <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">

        var count = 2;
        function validate() {
        var un = document.myform.username.value;
        var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
        var valid = false;

        var unArray = ["Philip", "George", "Sarah", "Michael"];  // as many as you like - no comma after final entry
        var pwArray = ["Password1", "Password2", "Password3", "Password4"];  // the corresponding passwords;

        for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
        break;
        }
        }

        if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "Books.html";
        return false;
        }

        var t = " tries";
        if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

        if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password.  You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
        }


        }

        </script>

        <form name = "myform">
        <p>ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="username"> ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="pword">
        <div id= "submit"><input type="button" value="Check In" name="Submit" onclick= "validate()"></div>
        </p>

        </form>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You've written all the client side code, do you have any server side code or a database setup?

Comment: Where's your Server code?

Comment: I haven't made any server code, should I just use php? or is like mySQL involved or any of that? I'd prefer php. Nor have I done any database setup. (sorry just trying to figure things out here)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a PHP signup/login page, look into using SESSION variables.  (http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Upon signing up, set a SESSION variable with the username and redirect the user to the login page.  The login page should look for a pre-existing $_SESSION['user'] variable and if it exists log them straight in.

Also note that your current code is horribly insecure.  You are authenticating with JS against an array of usernames and passwords.  Any hacker (and I use that term extremely loosely here) could simply look at the source and find a working username/password combination.  You should NEVER authenticate locally!

Comment: Absolutely.. that's what the site said where i got the code! No worries, very informal site and it does not matter! Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

```
function forgot(){
  event.preventDefault();

  var email = document.getElementById("fe").value;

  if(emailArray.indexOf(email) == -1){
    if (email == ""){
      alert("Email required.");
      return ;
    }
    alert("Email does not exist.");
    return ;
  }

  alert("email is send to your email check it in 24hr. \n Thanks");
  document.getElementById("fe").value ="";
}

document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Right Click is not allowed");
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
    var emailArray=[];
    var passwordArray=[];
    var loginBox = document.getElementById("login");
    var regBox = document.getElementById("register");
    var forgetBox = document.getElementById("forgot");

    var loginTab = document.getElementById("lt");
    var regTab = document.getElementById("rt");

    function regTabFun(){
        event.preventDefault();

        regBox.style.visibility="visible";
        loginBox.style.visibility="hidden";
        forgetBox.style.visibility="hidden";

        regTab.style.backgroundColor="rgb(12, 132, 189)";
        loginTab.style.backgroundColor="rgba(11, 177, 224, 0.82)";
    }
    function loginTabFun(){
        event.preventDefault();

        regBox.style.visibility="hidden";
        loginBox.style.visibility="visible";
        forgetBox.style.visibility="hidden";

        loginTab.style.backgroundColor="rgb(12, 132, 189)";
        regTab.style.backgroundColor="rgba(11, 177, 224, 0.82)";
    }
    function forTabFun(){
        event.preventDefault();

        regBox.style.visibility="hidden";
        loginBox.style.visibility="hidden";
        forgetBox.style.visibility="visible";

        regTab.style.backgroundColor="rgba(11, 177, 224, 0.82)";
        loginTab.style.backgroundColor="rgba(11, 177, 224, 0.82)";

    }


    function register(){
        event.preventDefault();

        var email = document.getElementById("re").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("rp").value;
        var passwordRetype = document.getElementById("rrp").value;

        if (email == ""){
            alert("Email required.");
            return ;
        }
        else if (password == ""){
            alert("Password required.");
            return ;
        }
        else if (passwordRetype == ""){
            alert("Password required.");
            return ;
        }
        else if ( password != passwordRetype ){
            alert("Password don't match retype your Password.");
            return;
        }
        else if(emailArray.indexOf(email) == -1){
            emailArray.push(email);
            passwordArray.push(password);

            alert(email + "  Thanks for registration. \nTry to login Now");

            document.getElementById("re").value ="";
            document.getElementById("rp").value="";
            document.getElementById("rrp").value="";
        }
        else{
            alert(email + " is already register.");
            return ;
        }
    }
    function login(){
        event.preventDefault();

        var email = document.getElementById("se").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("sp").value;

        var i = emailArray.indexOf(email);

        if(emailArray.indexOf(email) == -1){
            if (email == ""){
                alert("Email required.");
                return ;
            }
            alert("Email does not exist. Register First.");
            return ;
        }
        else if(passwordArray[i] != password){
            if (password == ""){
                alert("Confirm Password");
                return ;
            }
            alert("Password does not match.");
            return ;
        }
        else {
            alert(email + " yor are login Now \n welcome to our website.");

            document.getElementById("se").value ="";
            document.getElementById("sp").value="";
            location = "index.html" ;
        }

    }
    function forgot(){
        event.preventDefault();

        var email = document.getElementById("fe").value;

        if(emailArray.indexOf(email) == -1){
            if (email == ""){
                alert("Email required.");
                return ;
            }
            alert("Email does not exist.");
            return ;
        }

        alert("email is send to your email check it in 24hr. \n Thanks");
        document.getElementById("fe").value ="";
    }
```

[Code for CSS and HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/Shaurya4414G/3Lbh405v/)